# Flink buffer request blocking leads to low performance

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As for real-time streaming data platform on flink-1.1.5, I meet an issue.

**phenomenal description:** 
Our business logic of flink job is a generic ETL process which source operator and sink operator are both based on kafka and transform operators are some related etl logic. But the data from kafka topic which is read by source operator are in different size, such as one data is just less than 100 KB in non-peak hours but the other data are nearly 600KB in peak hours. In non-peak session, the performance of flink job is fine, nevertheless it is unsatisfactory in peak session which the performance decrease sharply and sustain the low state until the peak session go by and the performance will recover. As a consequence. I didn`t see any full GC cases happen on taskmanager and the system load of every taskmananger decreased during that period. Besides, there is no exception and extra error in logs. I can see that all threads are blocking at request buffer via JMX at that time.

**Related configuration and metircs:**

1. flink standalone cluster on 1.1.5 which has 1 jobmanager and 5 taskmanagers(each one has 18 slot which is less than CPU cores).
2. jdk version is 1.8 which GC type is G1.
3. source and sink are both kafka
4. job consistency type: exactly once
5. because the source partition amount of kafka topic is less than  transform operator amount, the parallelism of each operator is not quite the same and the task can not become one task chain as optimization.

[image]
[image]

**Based on what I describe above, we have tried some approaches:**

1. modify the memory-segment size, 32KB and 64KB
2. aggrandize the network buffer pool capacity,
3. modify kafka consumer API parameter
4. enhance flink cluster which add more taskmanager nodes and add more process threads.
5. decrease transform operator threads and keep the amount of source operator, all transform operator and sink operator as the same,  the task can become one task chain.

We had a try above #1,#2,#3,#4 approach but they does not work, just the #5 was effectual, but the #5 approach was not a excellent manner for us because its performance was declining.

Have you met this issue before? Is there any better approach to avoid this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a newer version of Flink, like `1.4.0` or `1.3.2`?

Comment: No, I haven`t, I just want to clarify what the root cause is because the flink job is on production environment, the solution of flink version promotion may be risk for us.

Comment: The profiling looks as if the Kafka consumers are backpressured because they are waiting for more buffers. On the other hand there is at least one downstream processor which is waiting for incoming data. This could be the  result of a checkpoint alignment were one task spilled a lot of data and now has to catch up with the data stream, effectively blocking also other tasks on the same TM. This behaviour got improved with Flink `1.3`.